# Brew in a bag (BIAB) material

Tags: all-grain, small-space, biab

Where can you buy and what type of material have you made a BIAB with? Specifically:

-Name/brand/type of material
-Mesh size
-Dimensions of raw material and final bag

Answer (score 1):

- Generic brand
- Nylon
- Fine mesh - the finer the better
- 20 inches deep by 18 inches wide

This bag holds at least eight pounds of grain.  I BIAB as my pilot system, making 1-3 gallon batches on my stove.

A friend of mine thinks any fine nylon mesh will work. You could make one from materials found in an arts & craft store like Michael's or Beverly's Fabrics.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used:

http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/90111980

It is sold as a curtain, it comes with two sheets measuring 94" X 110" and is made of polyester voile, don't know the mesh size.  I cut one sheet in half and fold it in half when I use it to line my insulated bottling bucket mash tun.  So my "bag" is 55" X 47" folded once.  I  rinse it off and toss it in the washer with my hop bags after brewing.  It cost $5 US, and is 4 times the material I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried two. I've used 100% polyester voile curtain material. You can find that at pretty much any fabric store and buy it by the yard. With that, I never bothered making a bag and things worked out well.

I recently decided to try a sparging bag in my now-insulated 6.5 gallon bottling bucket as an alternative, and I feel like I'm getting more positive results with that method because I can still drain through the grain bed for filtration (and you can lift it by the spigot for faster drainage).

I don't know exactly what brand it is, but it might be Bru-Heat. I purchased it from my LHBS and it is called "Sparging Bag for 6.5 Gallon Bucket." http://www.home-brew.com/mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=CTGY&Store_Code=EMP3373&Category_Code=BRUH